# Is order preserved in arrays when intersection is done?

Tags: ruby, arrays

When I do an intersection of two arrays, is there any guarantee that the resulting order is based on the order of the first array?

For example, if I have

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,2,1]
```

could `a & b` return `[3,2,1]`, instead of `[1,2,3]` (which is what I'd expect)?

I can't find anything directly addressing this in either RDoc's or the Pickaxe's documentation of Array.

RubySpec has a specification that it [creates an array with elements in order they are first encountered](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/array/intersection_spec.rb#L16), but should I assume YARV Ruby will honour that specification?

Comment: By quickly looking at the C code (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26), I would say that it seems to preserve the order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it is a guaranteed feature. They upgraded the RDoc description in [revision 39415](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/39415). It should be reflected sometime.

Answer (score 0):

YARV is official Ruby interpreter since version 1.9, so I assume it doeas honour that specification. And BTW, RubySpec was created as executable specification of the language, allowing developers to create their own interpreters that pass this spec and I believe that YARV was created with this in RubySpec in mind.

Comment: RubySpec has no official affiliation with Ruby’s development, so it doesn’t guarantee that MRI/YARV Ruby will always work that way, but more so just that it does now.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Sure, I'm not suggesting anything like that. I simply wanted to point this thing out and that, as I said, I believe that YARV was using this spec, like IronRuby for example.

Comment: RubySpec has no official affiliation, but it was part of the MRI test suite in 2010, and when I was working on it (as part of the IronRuby team), they were actively contributing to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee in the documentation but intersection follows the left-hand set's order.

The source shows that array `a` sets the order:

```
...
for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary1); i++) {
    vv = (st_data_t)(v = rb_ary_elt(ary1, i));
    if (st_delete(RHASH_TBL(hash), &vv, 0)) {
        rb_ary_push(ary3, v);
    }
}
...
```

It's simple to test:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,2,1]

a.size.times do
    puts "a = #{ a.join(',') }\ta & b = #{ (a & b).join(',') }\tb & a = #{ (b & a).join(',') }"
  a.rotate! 
end
```

Which outputs:

```
a = 1,2,3   a & b = 1,2,3   b & a = 3,2,1
a = 2,3,1   a & b = 2,3,1   b & a = 3,2,1
a = 3,1,2   a & b = 3,1,2   b & a = 3,2,1
```

That's using Ruby 1.9.3-p374

Comment: I think that's not the point. I think the OP knows that the order is preserved (at least under the current MRI implementation). What is asked is whether that is intended as a feature or not. In other words, if a new C algorithm to implement the method was found that does not preserve the order, will the future implementation not preserve the order, or will it preserve the order.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm You are welcome. I wasn't sure if you would notice. Hoped you would like that. http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7803