# Is sort in Ruby stable?

Tags: ruby, sorting

Is `sort` in Ruby stable? That is, for elements that are in a tie for `sort`, is the relative order among them preserved from the original order? For example, given:

```
a = [
  {id: :a, int: 3},
  {id: :b, int: 1},
  {id: :c, int: 2},
  {id: :d, int: 0},
  {id: :e, int: 1},
  {id: :f, int: 0},
  {id: :g, int: 1},
  {id: :h, int: 2},
]
```

is it guaranteed that we always get for

```
a.sort_by{|h| h[:int]}
```

the following

```
[
  {id: :d, int: 0},
  {id: :f, int: 0},
  {id: :b, int: 1},
  {id: :e, int: 1},
  {id: :g, int: 1},
  {id: :c, int: 2},
  {id: :h, int: 2},
  {id: :a, int: 3},
]
```

without any variation for the relative order among the elements with the `:id` value `:d`, `:f`, and among `:b`, `:e`, `:g`, and among `:c`, `:h`? If that is the case, where in the documentation is it described?

This question may or may not have connection with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764135).

Comment: No, at least not how you did it. How can `sort` guarantee the order of  two elements when their given comparators are the same?

Comment: @Linuxios: Some sorting algorithms are [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability).

Comment: @mu: Thanks. Interesting. I don't think Ruby's is though.

Comment: I got this answer                                                  => [{:id=>:f, :int=>0}, {:id=>:d, :int=>0}, {:id=>:e, :int=>1}, {:id=>:b, :int=>1}, {:id=>:g, :int=>1}, {:id=>:c, :int=>2}, {:id=>:h, :int=>2}, {:id=>:a, :int=>3}]

Comment: @beck03076 Would you change your second comment to an answer? I think it negatively answers my question. I don't understand your first comment.

Comment: @sawa I never answered your question. I was adding value to your question that, you cant guarantee the fact on a tie of 0's it didn't put :d before :f.

Comment: I think the real answer is "unspecified therefore implementation dependent".

Comment: @muistooshort I just realized that it is not guaranteed in MRI, which should be the norm. And thanks for letting me know the terminology.

Comment: @sawa AFAIK `Array#sort` algorithm has no stability specification and in MRI is implemented by *unstable* quicksort.

Comment: In windows 7 with MRI 2.3.0 no problem

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Both [MRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI)'s [sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) and [sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) are [unstable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). Some time ago there was a [request](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1089) to make them stable, but it was rejected. The reason: Ruby uses an [in-place quicksort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort),  which performs better if stability is not required. Note that you can still implement stable methods from unstable ones:

```
module Enumerable
  def stable_sort_by
    sort_by.with_index { |x, idx| [yield(x), idx] }
  end
end
```

Comment: Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort): *"Quicksort is a comparison sort and, in efficient implementations, is not a stable sort."*

Comment: furthermore, if any sort implementation doesn't say it's stable in its contract, it's always wrong to rely on it being stable.

Comment: Your implementation of `stable_sort` does not respect the signature of `sort` that accepts a comparator.

Comment: Ruby's sort sometimes _is_ stable (but you shouldn't depend on it).  I think that this sometimes-stability did not exist when this answer was created.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442298/is-sort-in-ruby-stable/44486562#44486562) for details.

Answer (score 20):

No, ruby's built-in sort is not stable.

If you want stable sort, this should work. You probably want to create a method for it if you're going to use it often.

```
a.each_with_index.sort_by {|h, idx| [h[:int], idx] }.map(&:first)
```

Basically it keeps track of the original array index of each item, and uses it as a tie-breaker when `h[:int]` is the same.

**More info, for the curious:**

As far as I know, using the original array index as the tie-breaker is the only way to guarantee stability when using an unstable sort. The actual attributes (or other data) of the items will not tell you their original order.

Your example is somewhat contrived because the `:id` keys are sorted ascending in the original array. Suppose the original array were sorted descending by `:id`; you'd want the `:id`'s in the result to be descending when tie-breaking, like so:

```
[
 {:id=>:f, :int=>0},
 {:id=>:d, :int=>0},
 {:id=>:g, :int=>1},
 {:id=>:e, :int=>1},
 {:id=>:b, :int=>1},
 {:id=>:h, :int=>2},
 {:id=>:c, :int=>2},
 {:id=>:a, :int=>3}
]
```

Using the original index will handle this too.

**Update:**

Matz's own suggestion (see [this page](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.ruby/JcDGbaFHifI/2gKpc9FQbCoJ)) is similar, and may be slightly more efficient than the above:

```
n = 0
ary.sort_by {|x| n+= 1; [x, n]}
```

Answer (score 16):

For some implementations of Ruby, sort is stable, but you shouldn't depend upon it.  Stability of Ruby's sort is implementation defined.

## What the documentation says

[The documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) says that you should not depend upon sort being stable:

> The result is not guaranteed to be stable. When the comparison of two elements returns 0, the order of the elements is unpredictable.

Note that this does not say whether or not the sort is stable.  It just says it is not guaranteed to be stable.  Any given implementation of Ruby could have a stable sort and still be consistent with the documentation.  It could also have an unstable sort, or change whether the sort is stable at any time.

## What Ruby actually does

This test code prints `true` if Ruby's sort is stable, or `false` if it is not:

```
Foo = Struct.new(:value, :original_order) do
  def <=>(foo)
    value <=> foo.value
  end
end

size = 1000
unsorted = size.times.map do |original_order|
  value = rand(size / 10)
  Foo.new(value, original_order)
end
sorted = unsorted.sort
stably_sorted = unsorted.sort_by do |foo|
  [foo.value, foo.original_order]
end
p [RUBY_PLATFORM, RUBY_VERSION, RUBY_PATCHLEVEL, sorted == stably_sorted]
```

Here are the results for all of the Rubies I have installed on my Linux box:

```
["java", "1.8.7", 357, false]
["java", "1.9.3", 551, false]
["java", "2.3.3", 0, true]
["java", "2.5.7", 0, true]
["x86_64-linux", "1.8.7", 374, false]
["x86_64-linux", "1.8.7", 374, false]
["x86_64-linux", "1.8.7", 376, false]
["x86_64-linux", "1.9.3", 392, false]
["x86_64-linux", "1.9.3", 484, false]
["x86_64-linux", "1.9.3", 551, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.0.0", 643, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.0.0", 648, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.1.0", 0, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.1.10", 492, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.1.1", 76, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.1.2", 95, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.1.3", 242, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.1.4", 265, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.1.5", 273, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.1.6", 336, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.1.7", 400, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.1.8", 440, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.1.9", 490, false]
["x86_64-linux", "2.2.0", 0, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.2.1", 85, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.2.2", 95, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.2.3", 173, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.2.4", 230, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.2.5", 319, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.2.6", 396, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.3.0", 0, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.3.1", 112, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.3.2", 217, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.3.3", 222, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.4.0", 0, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.4.0", -1, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.4.0", -1, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.4.0", -1, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.4.0", -1, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.4.1", 111, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.4.2", 198, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.4.5", 335, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.4.9", 362, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.5.0", 0, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.5.3", 105, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.5.7", 206, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.6.0", 0, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.6.2", 47, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.6.3", 62, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.6.4", 104, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.6.5", 114, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.6.6", 146, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.7.0", 0, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.7.1", 83, true]
["x86_64-linux", "2.7.2", 137, true]
["x86_64-linux", "3.0.0", 0, true]
["x86_64-linux", "3.0.0", -1, true]
["x86_64-linux", "3.0.1", 64, true]
["x86_64-linux", "3.0.2", 107, true]
["x86_64-linux", "3.0.3", 157, true]
["x86_64-linux", "3.1.0", 0, true]
["x86_64-linux", "3.1.1", 18, true]
["x86_64-linux", "3.1.2", 20, true]
["x86_64-linux", "3.1.3", 185, true]
["x86_64-linux", "3.2.0", 0, true]
["x86_64-linux", "3.2.1", 31, true]
```

We can see that JRuby is unstable, and MRI before 2.2, on Linux, is unstable.  MRI >= 2.2.0 is stable (again, on Linux).

The platform matters, though.  Although the above result shows that sort is stable in MRI 2.4.1 on Linux, the same version is unstable on Windows:

```
["x64-mingw32", "2.4.1", 111, false]
```

## Why is MRI's sort stable on Linux, but not on Windows?

Even within a single version of a Ruby implementation, the sort algorithm can change.  MRI can use at least three different sorts.  The sort routine is selected at compile time using a series of #ifdefs in [util.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/5aff6f294821574e54f458d547cf9641dd2eca98/util.c).  It looks like MRI has the ability to use sorts from at least two different libraries.  It also has its own implementation.

## What should you do about it?

Since the sort may be stable but can't be guaranteed to be stable, do not write code which depends upon Ruby's sort being stable.  That code could break when used on a different version, implementation, or platform.

Comment: "happens to be" stable is very different to "is guaranteed to be" stable. Unless you want bugs which appear without warning when changing Ruby versions or platforms, my advice is to ignore implementations that happen to be stable.

Comment: @DaveSlutzkin I agree.  I said this ("but you shouldn't depend upon it"), but perhaps not clearly enough if you didn't catch it.  I will add more words.

Answer (score -4):

personally I wouldn't count on this. How bout doing something like this:

```
a.sort {|a, b| s1 = a[:int] <=> b[:int]; s1 != 0 ? s1 : a[:id] <=> b[:id] }
```

Comment: That is neither answering my question nor giving the same result as if the answer to my question is positive.