# In an array of hashes, how can I edit a specific hash' index?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand the `sort_by` method. Here's a script I'm experimenting with:

```
def test(x)
  if x[:type] == 1
    # move the hash to the first index of the array
  end
end


values = [{value: "First", type: 0},{value: "Second", type: 1},{value: "1111", type: 0},{value: "2222", type: 1}]
values.sort_by! { |x| test(x) }
puts values
```

How can I explicitly state the index I wish the selected index to be moved to? I want the hashes with a type of 1 to all be moved to the first three indexes, and their order not changed.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want using `sort_by` (except that the original order is not preserved if two elements return same value but it shows how sort_by works)

```
values.sort_by! { |x| x[:type] == 1 ? 0 : 1 }
# =>  [{:value=>"2222", :type=>1}, {:value=>"Second", :type=>1}, 
#      {:value=>"1111", :type=>0}, {:value=>"First", :type=>0}]
```

`sort_by` sorts the elements in ascending order based on the value returned by the block.

In this case, it iterates over the array the and passes each element to the following block as `x`

```
 { |x| x[:type] == 1 ? 0 : 1 }
```

The value returned from the above block is compared to each other and used to create the final ordered array.

In this case,  the value returned is `0` if `x[:type] == 1` and `1` otherwise. So all elements with `x[:type] == 1` will be ordered first.

See more info on `sort_by` [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)

Comment: Could you explain 'value returned' a bit more please? What exactly uses  this value?

Comment: added some more explanation.

Comment: Understand '|x| x[:type] == 1 ?' completely, and how it iterates over the array. I understand that the value to the left of the colon is 'returned' when 'x[:type] == 1 ?' is true, and the value to the right of the colon is 'returned' when it is false. But I still don't quite understand how these values are used...when you say the value returned is 0 you sort of mean the current hash' index is set to 0 inside the array?

Comment: Where can I learn more about this syntax, { |x| x[:type] == 1 ? 0 : 1 }, it's really new!

Comment: This answer will not work. Ruby `sort`, `sort_by` are not stable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442298/is-sort-in-ruby-stable

Comment: @Starkers if you read the docs linked in the answer, it has a good explanation on what `sort_by` does behind the scenes. @sawa yes they are not stable but I think OP wanted to understand `sort_by`, I will edit to make that clear.

Comment: @tihom "The block should return -1, 0, or +1 depending on the comparison between a and b. " What is the significance of this? What uses these returned values?

Comment: note that it is in the explanation for `sort` ,  when two elements a and b are compared : -1 means a is less than b , 0 means they are equal and +1 means a is greater than b. This is then used to sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

To use `sort_by` here, you need to find a way to keep the ordering correct.  Here's one, though it's a bit of a hack:

```
values = [{value: "First", type: 0}, {value: "Second", type: 1},
          {value: "1111", type: 0},  {value: "2222", type: 1}]
type = 1
n = values.size # => 4
values.each_with_index {|h,i| h[:type] = i-n if h[:type] == type}
    # => [{:value=>"First", :type=>0}, {:value=>"Second", :type=>-3},    
          {:value=>"1111", :type=>0},  {:value=>"2222", :type=>-1}]
values.sort_by! {|h| h[:type]}
    # => [{:value=>"Second", :type=>-3}, {:value=>"2222", :type=>-1},
          {:value=>"1111", :type=>0}, {:value=>"First", :type=>0}]
values.map {|h| h[:type] = type if h[:type] < 0; h}
    # => [{:value=>"Second", :type=>1}, {:value=>"2222", :type=>1},
          {:value=>"1111", :type=>0}, {:value=>"First", :type=>0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

values.sort_by{|x| x[:type]}

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, when using #sort or #sort_by, declare the index to which a item should be moved.  You can, however, specify the order and let #sort_by do the rest.

The first problem is that sort_by is not stable: Equal items may be emitted in any order.  You require a stable sort, so let's monkey-patch Enumerable to have a #stable_sort_by method:

```
module Enumerable
  def stable_sort_by
    map.each.with_index.sort_by do |e, i|
      [yield(e), i]
    end.map(&:first)
  end
end
```

This sorts according to the values returned by the block, just as #sort_by does, but if the values are equal, it sorts by the items order.  This preserves the relative order of equal items.

Now, using the newly defined #stable_sort_by:

```
values.sort_by! do |h|
  if h[:type] == 1
    0
  else
    1
  end
end
```

This moves to the beginning all items having a *type* of 1, but otherwise leaves the relative order of items unchanged.