# Stable #sort taking a block

Tags: ruby, sorting

We find [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sort_stability#Stable_sort_in_Ruby) an implementation of a stable sort_by in Ruby, which works for the general case (i.e. I can supply my own comparision algorithm), and in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442298/is-sort-in-ruby-stable) user tokland describes a very elegant way to do a stable sort_by:

```
module Enumerable 
  def stable_sort_by 
    sort_by.with_index { |x, idx| [yield(x), idx] } 
  end 
end
```

The idea of using an Enumerator object together with *with_index* is surprisingly simple! I would like to find a similar elegant solution to create a stable version of the #sort function where it is given a comparison block.  It would be used like this:

```
sorted_people = people.stable_sort do |person|
  person.name
end
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean. The cited method takes a block in which you express the comparison function.

Comment: `[..., idx]` merely ensures that *equal* items (according to the block) keep their relative positions.

Comment: In this case, the block doesn't express a comparision function (because if it would be the case, we would need to items from the array, say: x and y (together with their indices). Here, we have only one array element with the index, and as Stefan correctly pointed out, idx is needed for disambiguation, if two elements have the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution (but far from elegant):

```
module Enumerable
  def stable_sort
    each_with_index.sort { |(x, i), (y, j)|
      r = yield(x, y)
      r == 0 ? i <=> j : r
    }.map(&:first)
  end
end
```

It generates an array of `[element, index]` pairs and sorts them by passing each two elements to the given block (just like `sort` does). If the block returns `0`, it compares the indices, otherwise, it returns the block's result. Afterwards, the elements are extracted from the generated array.

Example:

```
arr = [[2, :baz], [1,:foo], [1, :bar]]

arr.sort { |x, y| x[0] <=> y[0] }
#=> [[1, :bar], [1, :foo], [2, :baz]]

arr.stable_sort { |x, y| x[0] <=> y[0] }
#=> [[1, :foo], [1, :bar], [2, :baz]]
```