# Sorting a string by last names: Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, algorithm, sorting

Finding this coding challenge rather tricky and can't seem to figure out what method I should add to **explicitly sort** the last names of a string.

**Current solution:**

```
def sort_reindeer reindeer_names
  return sorted_names = reindeer_names.sort_by do |name|
    name.split(" ").reverse.join
  end
end
```

**Outcome:**

```
# issue: Expected: ["Kenjiro Mori", "Susumu Mori", "Akira Mori"]
# => instead got: ["Akira Mori", "Kenjiro Mori", "Susumu Mori"]
```

It looks like my code has seen that each last name is a match and has decided to map over first names and return them in alphabetical order. How can I stop my code from ordering the first name if the last names match? would you advise that I create some sort of ternary statement or is there a simpler fix.

Comment: What is the input that leads to the failed test? What is the rule for determining the sort order in case the last names are the same? Is the sort required to be stable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for technicalities, you don't need explicit `return` or setting `sorted_names` local variable.

Ad rem: Instead of doing `name.split(' ').reverse.join`, which sorts by first word as well (if the last words are equal), you can do: `name.split(' ').last`, so it only takes last word into account. The result is:

```
def sort_reindeer(reinder_names)
  reinder_names.sort_by { |name| name.split(' ').last }
end

sort_reindeer(["Kenjiro Mori", "Susumu Mori", "Akira Mori"])
# => ["Kenjiro Mori", "Susumu Mori", "Akira Mori"]
```

Comment: This works on some, but not all Ruby implementations, because `sort_by` is not guaranteed to be stable. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15442298/967621

Comment: ...a variant: `reindeer_names.sort_by { |name| name[/[^ ]+\A/] }`.