# Ruby sort_by keep original order of not sorted

Tags: ruby

I have a hash that looks something like:

```
{ "3g3dsd3" => {"price"=>0.12, "avg"=>81, "top"=>true}, "1sf3af" => {"price"=>0.14, "avg"=>121, "top"=>false}...}
```

I wanna reorder it so that items with `"top"=>true` would be on top but besides that the items would keep the previous order, meaning items with the same `top` value wont change the order between when.

I could not find evidence in the original doc that `sort_by` keeps the order of the attributes that are not sorted.

How can I do that?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442298/is-sort-in-ruby-stable

Comment: Please clarify "would be on top". When you give an example it is helpful to readers for the inputs to be valid Ruby objects (no "..." and here you need a closing `}`) and for you to show the desired result (another Ruby object). As well as clarifying the question that allows those giving answers to demonstrate that the code they suggest produces the desired result. Lastly, it is helpful to assign a variable to each input (e.g., `h = { "3g3dsd3" => ... }`) so readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `sort_by` stable by incorporating `with_index`.

Instead of:

```
collection.sort_by { |...| ... }
```

You write:

```
collection.sort_by.with_index { |(...), i| [..., i] }
```

Applied to your problem:

```
hash.sort_by { |_k, v| v['top'] ? 0 : 1 }                      # unstable

hash.sort_by.with_index { |(_k, v), i| [v['top'] ? 0 : 1, i] } # stable
```

Answer (score 1):

[`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) specifically states:

> The result is not guaranteed to be stable. When two keys are equal, the order of the corresponding elements is unpredictable.

Meaning your question is well founded.

In this scenario you could use [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) to split the collection up into two. Then paste them back together in the way you desire.

```
top, non_top = hash.partition { |key, hash| hash['top'] }
result = (top + non_top).to_h
```

`partition` keeps the order of the of the original array.

---

If you are a fan of one liners, the following does the same in this scenario.

```
result = hash.partition { |key, hash| hash['top'] }.flatten(1).to_h
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
The partition works fine for me but after going `(top + non_top).to_h`  the hash mixes all over again (not ordered by the `top` field)

Comment: user2101699, please check your work. I am certain this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby `sort / sort_by` are not stable. You can however use the index in the original input as a tiebreaker: [Is sort in Ruby stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442298/is-sort-in-ruby-stable)

Comment: So how can I go around it? can I use the original index as part of the sort params?

Comment: @user2101699 yes, see the link and the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to reorder the hash's key-value pairs without converting the hash to one or more arrays and then converting those arrays, after modification, back to a hash.

Suppose

```
h = { "2rh4abc" => {"price"=>0.18, "avg"=>130, "top"=>false },
      "3g3dsd3" => {"price"=>0.12, "avg"=>81,  "top"=>true  },
      "1sf3af"  => {"price"=>0.14, "avg"=>121, "top"=>false } }
```

then

```
top_key = h.find { |_,v| v["top"] == true }.first
  #=> "3g3dsd3"
{ top_key=>h[top_key] }.merge(h.reject { |k,_| k == top_key })
  #=> {"3g3dsd3"=>{"price"=>0.12, "avg"=>81, "top"=>true},
  #    "2rh4abc"=>{"price"=>0.18, "avg"=>130, "top"=>false},
  #    "1sf3af"=>{"price"=>0.14, "avg"=>121, "top"=>false}}
```

---

If `h` can be mutated (modified in place) this can be simplified to:

```
{ top_key=>h.delete(top_key) }.merge(h)
  #=> {"3g3dsd3"=>{"price"=>0.12, "avg"=>81, "top"=>true},
  #    "2rh4abc"=>{"price"=>0.18, "avg"=>130, "top"=>false},    
  #    "1sf3af"=>{"price"=>0.14, "avg"=>121, "top"=>false}}
```